# Bootstrap-table best approach to develop custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Using [Bootstrap-Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) (version 1.20 and 1.21.4) i would  make a columns dropdown list dependent on another columns selected value.
I've for example 3 columns with the respective drop-down boxes to apply the filter, and when i select an item in the first dropdown-list the second and third dropdown select filter should propose the values related to the first choice.

Used also option "hideUnusedSelectOptions" but not always it runs.

Now i've decided to develop a custom filter function.

1. Listen the event 'column-search.bs.table' to capture which dropdown was chosen.
2. Populate others dropdown in the 'page-change.bs.table' event; now data are still filtered
   with relatives values dependent on first choice.

The problem is that with this approach the first one dropdown, where i choice the option, remains blank with no value.

May be the problem is applying

```
$table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', newFilter)
```

which triggers another series of events starting from 'page-change.bs.table'.

At this point i don't know what to do.

```
  $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
        
    var event='page-change.bs.table';
    var pref = '.bootstrap-table-filter-control-';
    if (name == event && DataLoadedInTable == true && filterApplied == true)
    {
        
        switch (filterField)
        {
            case 'DEPARTMENT':
            case 'UO_DESC':
            case 'LEVPROF':
                var data = $("#table").bootstrapTable('getData', { unfiltered: false, includeHiddenRows:false});
                break;
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
        FilterApplied1Time = true;
       
       if (filterField != 'DEPARTMENT' && FirstFilterApplied !='DEPARTMENT') 
        {
            let xx = UniqueListFromData(data, '');
            fillSELECT(pref + 'DEPARTMENT', xx);
            
        }
        if (filterField != 'UO_DESC' && FirstFilterApplied !='UO_DESC')  {
            let xx = UniqueListFromData(data, 'UO_DESC');
            fillSELECT(pref + 'UO_DESC', xx);
        }
        if (filterField != 'LEVEL' && FirstFilterApplied !='LEVEL')  {
            xx = UniqueListFromData(data, 'LEVEL');
            fillSELECT(pref + 'LEVEL', xx);
        }
        if (filterField != 'LEVPROF' && FirstFilterApplied !='LEVPROF')  {
            xx = UniqueListFromData(data, 'LEVPROF');
            fillSELECT(pref + 'LEVPROF', xx);
        }
     };
  
})

$table.on('column-search.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
        //Fired when we are searching into the column data
           
    if ((DataLoadedInTable == true && args != '') || FilterApplied1Time==true)
    {
        filterField = name;
        if (filterField == filterFirstApplied)
        {
            //This is executed when you choose the first SELECT type chosen 
            var ctl=".bootstrap-table-filter-control-" + filterField ;
            var myval =  GetSelectedOption(ctl);
            ResetInAction = true;
          
            var key = filterField;
            var newFilter = {};
            newFilter[key] = myval;

            filterApplied=false;
            LastFilter = newFilter;
            
            $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy', newFilter)
            $(ctl + " option[value='" + myval + "']").attr('selected','selected');
           
            filterApplied = true;
            myFilter[filterField] = (args != '' ? true : false);
            
            ResetInAction = false;

            return false;
        }
        switch (name) {
            case 'DEPARTMENT':
            case 'UO_DESC':
            case .....:
                filterApplied = true;
                myFilter[filterField] = (args != '' ? true : false);
                if (filterFirstApplied == '') {filterFirstApplied=name;};
                break;
            default:
                
        }
    }
})

 

$table.on('search.bs.table', function (name) {


    if ($(".bootstrap-table-filter-control-UO_DESC option:selected").text() == '')
         { myFilter.UO_DESC = false; };
    if ($(".bootstrap-table-filter-control-DEPARTMENT option:selected").text() == '')
    { myFilter.DEPARTMENT = false; };

    var data = $("#table").bootstrapTable('getData', { unfiltered: true, includeHiddenRows:true});
  
    var b = Object.keys(myFilter).every((k) => !myFilter[k]);
    if (b == true) {
        FilterApplied=false;
        FilterApplied1Time=false;
        filterFirstApplied='';
    }
  

});


.......



function UniqueListFromData(data, fieldName) {

var xx = $.map(data, function (Field, e1) {
    return Field[fieldName];
}, []);
var uniqueList = UniqueList(xx).sort();
return uniqueList;
}

function UniqueList(list) {
var result = [];
$.each(list, function (i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
});
return result;
}
```